# Background color is not the exact color I set

Tags: rendering, world

When rendering the background color is not the exact color that I set under the world settings. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: So it turns out that in the Filmic "View" option (found under the "Render" section of the "Color Management" tab in the Scene properties) the color you set for the world is not the exact color that will be used. The actual color of the background will be slightly darker. Changing the color space doesn't change it though.